# i18n in asp.net using resources and entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, resources

I've been trying to store my strings in a database using resource files to fetch them. I've been following the guide from http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx
The example works fine enough when i use his sql code based on ADO.net to fetch the strings from the database.
But i want to use Entity Framework to fetch the strings from the database, because my translation table is quite different. Could anyone show me an example of how to use Entity Framework in the resource project(assembly?), because i can't seem to get it to work. I cant import any of my models or contexts from my main project with "using", and it tells me i have duplicate models when i copy them to the resources project/assembly